# C# Minesweeper project

Tags: c#, minesweeper

I made a very simple Minesweeper using C# and WPF. My method for checking the adjacent mines for buttons is pretty long and could use some improvements, so how would I make it shorter and more "reasonable" so that it would not take so many code lines?

**MiniMine.cs**

```
namespace boardgame
{
    class MiniMine : boardGame

    {
        //MineBoard gameboard;
        private MiinaAlusta gameboard;

        //row 
        private const int row = 6;

        // Column
        private const int colum = 6;

        //ButtonCount = row*row
        public const int buttonCount = row * row;

        //MineCount = 10
        private const int minecount = 10;

        //Mine
        private const string mine = "*";

        //Empty
        public const string Empty = "";

        //Content
        private string[] content = new string[buttonCount];

        //MineInfor
        private int[] mineinfo = new int[buttonCount];

        //Points
        private int points;

        //Mines string 
        private List<int> mines = new List<int>(minecount);

        //Cells
        new protected Button[] cells = new Button[buttonCount];

        // Default constructor
        public MiniMine()
        {

        }

        //Cells are herited from BoardGame class
        public MiniMine(UserControl MineBoard)
        {     
            cells = new Button[buttonCount];
            gameboard.mineBoard.Children.CopyTo(cells, 10); 
        }


        public new void Play(object sender)
        {
            Button bttn = (Button)sender;
            int index = gameboard.MiniMiinaLauta.Children.IndexOf(btn);

            // Checks if index is found from Mines list.
            if (mines.Contains(index)) 
            {

                btn.IsEnabled = false;
                ((Button)cells[index]).Content = mine;

                // IF button containts a mine, alert the user and call the method to show all mines.        
                MessageBox.Show("Game Over!"); // Its a hit!
                ClearMines();

            }
            // If mine is not found from the list, skip button disable and increase point counter.
            else 
            {
                cells[index].IsEnabled = true;
               // SHows nearby mines.
              ((Button)cells[index]).Content = MineInfo(index,row,buttonCount); 
                //((Button)ruudut[index]).Content = MiinaInfo(index); 
                gameboard.points.Content = ("Points: " + points); 

                // 
                if (points == 15) // If points reach 25 you win the game.
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Victory!"); 

                }
            }
        }


        // Method to randomize mine positions on the board and set them to the board.
        private void setMines()

        {
            for (int i = 0; i < minecount; i--)
            {
                Random ran = new Random();
                int random = ran.Next(0, 16);
                // if button containts a mine, creates a new index for the mine.
                while (mines.Contains(random)) 
                {
                    random = ran.Next(0,16);
                }
                mines.Add(random1);
            }

        }         
        // Method to Reset the game.

        public override void Reset()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++)
            {
                ((Button)cells[i]).Content = Empty;
                cells[i].IsEnabled = true;
            }
            mines.Clear();
            setMines();
            points = 0;
            gameboard.points.Content = "Points: 0";

        }

        // method to block new moves after you have either won or lost before you press new game again.
        public void blockMoves()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < cells.Length; i++) 
            {
                cells[i].IsEnabled = false; 
            }
        }

        // Shows all the methods and disables grids.

        private void ShowMines()
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < minecount; j++)
            {
                ((Button)cells[mines[j]]).Content = mine;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++)
            {
                cells[i].IsEnabled = false;
            }
        }

private int MiinaInfo(int index)
//shows how many mines one button can see
{
   // amount of mines = m
   int m = 0;
   #region edges
   if (index == 0)
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index + 5))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index +8))
       {
           m--;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 7))
       {
           m++;
       }
   }
   if (index == 1)
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index - 1))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 6))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 5))
       {
           m-+;
       }
   }
   if (index == 90)
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index - 1))
       {
           m--;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 6))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 5))
       {
           m--;
       }
   }
   if (index == 35)
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index - 1))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 6))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 7))
       {
           m++;
       }
   }
   #endregion
   #region toprow
   if (index > 0 && index < 5)
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index - 1))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 1))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 6))
       {
           m--;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 5))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 7))
       {
           m--;
       }
   }

   if (index => 30 && index =< 35)
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index - 1))
       {
           m--;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 1))
       {
           m--;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 6))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 5))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 7))
       {
           m++;
       }
   }

   if ((index => 6) || (index >= 12) || (index <= 18) || (index >= 24))
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index +5))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 7))
       {
           m--;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 1))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 5))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 7))
       {
           m++;
       }
   }

   if ((index != 11) || (index =>17) ||  (index <= 29))
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index + 8))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 8))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 8))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 8))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 5))
       {
           m++;
       }
   }

   if ((index => 6) || (index > 12 && index < 17))
   {
       if (mines.Contains(index + 1))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 11))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 6))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 6))
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 7)) 
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 7)) 
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index - 5)) 
       {
           m++;
       }
       if (mines.Contains(index + 5)) 
       {
           m++;
       }
   }
   return m;
}






        //mehtod that shows mineInfo
        private void showMineInfo()
```

buttons.
                for (int i = 0; i <= buttonCount; i++)
                {

```
                if (((Button)cells[i]).IsEnabled == true)
                    ((Button)cells[i]).Content = mineinfo[i].ToString();
                else
                    ((Button)cells[i]).Content = Empty;
            }
        }
    }    
    }
```

**MiineBoard.xaml**

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="pelilau.MineBoard"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:pelilautaprojekti"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="99900" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <Grid>

        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property ="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property ="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <TextBlock>
                Minesweeper
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>

        <Button Content="NEW GAME" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="31" Margin="-1,358,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" Click="Uusi_Click"/>
        <Label x:Name="points" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  VerticalAlignment="bottom" Width="79" Margin="0,0,50,10"/>

        <UniformGrid Name="MiniMine" Margin="0,29,0,58" >
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold" Height="52" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button Content=""  Click="Button_Click" FontSize="48" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </UniformGrid>

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

**xaml.cs**

```cs
namespace gameboard
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MineBoard.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MiineBoard : UserControl
    {
        //internal object MiniMine

        private MiniMine game;

        private int row = 6;

        private int buttoncount = 6 * 6;

        public MineReset()

            InitializeComponent();
            newgame = new MiniMine(this);
        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            game.Play(sender);
        }

        private void Uusi_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            game.Reset();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Miks tääll on suomea?  Lots of people here may have a hard time understanding various names sch as MiinaInfo and MiinaLauta.

Comment: The MiinaInfo function needs to be fixed.  Perhaps split index into x and y and only use  a few generic conditionals.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: I can see that it is Finnish, but I'm not so good at that language :)

Comment: @Daniel: Please don't edit the code in your question (see the link posted by Heslacher for why not). Your most recent edit (#6) introduces clearly broken code compared to the previous state.

Comment: That doesn't seem an actual, compilable code; rather some parts, randomly copied-and-pasted. Please verify the word 'buttons.' just after `private void showMineInfo()` function header.

Comment: This code does not agree with the intention decribed in the comment: `if (points == 15) // If points reach 25 you win the game.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write the `MiinaInfo` function like this:

```
class Minesweeper
{
    HashSet<int> mines = new HashSet<int>();
    int row = 6;
    int column = 6;

    int xy(int x, int y) => y * column + x;

    private int MiinaInfo(int index)
    {
        var x = index % column;
        var y = index / column;

        // Is {x,y} {plus,minus} 1 ok?
        bool xm1 = x - 1 >= 0, xp1 = x + 1 < column;
        bool ym1 = y - 1 >= 0, yp1 = y + 1 < row;
        bool ___ = true;

        return 0
            + (xm1 && ym1 && mines.Contains(xy(x - 1, y - 1)) ? 1 : 0)
            + (___ && ym1 && mines.Contains(xy(x + 0, y - 1)) ? 1 : 0)
            + (xp1 && ym1 && mines.Contains(xy(x + 1, y - 1)) ? 1 : 0)
            + (xm1 && ___ && mines.Contains(xy(x - 1, y + 0)) ? 1 : 0)
            + 0 // Center does not count.
            + (xp1 && ___ && mines.Contains(xy(x + 1, y + 0)) ? 1 : 0)
            + (xm1 && yp1 && mines.Contains(xy(x - 1, y + 1)) ? 1 : 0)
            + (___ && yp1 && mines.Contains(xy(x + 0, y + 1)) ? 1 : 0)
            + (xp1 && yp1 && mines.Contains(xy(x + 1, y + 1)) ? 1 : 0)
            + 0;
    }
}
```

It may be harder to read at first sight, but it actually is quite simple.

First, the index is converted into its `x` and `y` parts. Since the code does not use fixed numbers like `35`, it easily applies to rectangular fields of any size.

I chose the very short variable names `xm1, xp1, ym1, yp1` because they should have the same length, and `minus` and `plus` don't have that.

When you read the code in columns, it always follows the pattern (-1, 0, +1), or (xm1, ___, xp1). Therefore it should be easy to verify it for typos. Each of the 8 neighbors has one line of check, starting in the upper left, in typical European reading direction.

The `xy` function converts a pair of coordinates back into an index, as required by the `mines` field.

Answer (score 6):

**Use an appropriate data structure**

You're working with a 2D field, so why not use a 2D array to represent it?

```
bool[,] mines = new bool[columns, rows];
bool hasMine = mines[x, y];
```

That allows you to greatly simplify `MiinaInfo`:

```
private int GetNeighboringMineCount(int x, int y)
{
    int mineCount = 0;
    for (int nx = x - 1; nx <= x + 1; nx++)
    {
        if (nx < 0 || nx >= columns)
            continue;  // Don't go out of bounds

        for (int ny = y - 1; ny <= y + 1; ny++)
        {
            if (ny < 0 || ny >= rows)
                continue;  // Don't go out of bounds

            if (nx == x && ny == y)
                continue;  // Don't count the cell itself

            if (mines[nx, ny])
                mineCount += 1;
        }
    }
    return mineCount;
}
```

You may also want to add a method to your `MiinaAlusta` class for conveniently getting the button for a certain x,y coordinate. At that point your game code can work exclusively with x,y coordinates instead of indices.

**The use of Random**

Don't create new `Random` instances for each random number. Create a single instance and reuse it.

`Random` isn't really random, it's a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG). It generates numbers based on some internal state, which is updated each time a number is generated, so it's actually a deterministic sequence. This internal state needs to be initialized, which you can do explicitly by passing a seed value to `Random`'s constructor. Without a seed value, it'll look at the current time to initialize itself. So if you create multiple `Random` instances in rapid succession, several (or all) of them will end up with the same initialization value, and they'll generate the exact same numbers.

**Further comments**

- That xaml file contains a lot of buttons. Why not create them with a loop (in the code-behind file) instead? That would also allow you to support different field sizes.
- It looks like `buttonCount = row * row` should've been `buttonCount = column * row`.
- You've got `const` fields for the number of columns and rows, but you're not using them everywhere - the are still some places that use hard-coded numbers. That sort of duplication makes code hard to maintain.
- `Play` and `MiinaInfo` aren't very descriptive names. I'd probably rename `Play` to `RevealCell`, and `MiinaInfo` to something like `GetNeighboringMineCount`.
- Some method names start with a lowercase letter, others with an uppercase letter. That's not very consistent. In C# the convention is that method names start with an uppercase letter.
- In `Play`, you're using both `btn` and `(Button)cells[index]`, even though they both refer to the same button.
- In various places you're casting `cells[index]` to `Button`, even though `cells` is already of type `Button[]`. Those casts aren't necessary.
- `ShowMines` could call `blockMoves`, instead of duplicating that code.
- `showMineInfo` appears to be unused, so it can be removed.
- `setMines` could call `mines.Clear()` itself, instead of relying on `Reset` to do that.
- Some comments just repeat a variable or method name, which doesn't really add value.
- Regions can be useful to organize code, but using them within a method seems a bit excessive to me.